# Codeine vs Morphine competition for UGT2B7 and CYP3A4

Tags: drug-metabolism, opioids-opiates

Codeine and morphine are metabolized by the same key enzymes UGT2B7 and CYP3A4. Obviously codeine and morphine should inhibit each other's metabolism.
Did anyone experimentally measure this competition using purified/recombinant enzymes?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?